# setLabel in the Zend_Form_Element itself

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I normally need 2 lines to create an element and set its label.

```
$name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
$name->setLabel('name');
```

Is there a different syntax that lets me set the label at the same time, maybe as an option given to Zend_Form_Element_Text, so I end up with just 1 line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name',array('label' => 'name'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

`$name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name', array('label' => 'Your name'));`

But is keeping it to one line really that important? Typically, I do something like this:

```
// Inside a form class, so $this represents the form itself
$name = $this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
    'label'        => 'Your name',
    'description'  => 'Type your name here',
    'filters'      => array(
        'StringTrim', 
        // other filters
    ),
    'validators'   => array(
        'NotEmpty',
        // other validators
    ),
));
```